# How to run a python code until the condition is satisfied

Tags: python, loops

Below is my code :

```
import time
import pyautogui


location = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('ok.png')

pyautogui.click(location)
```

Now I don't know when the "OK" image appears. So I want to loop the code to search for the image until it is found. Otherwise it is terminating immediately before the image appears.
Once found break the loop and click that image.

How do I do I do that?

And time.sleep() dosent work because the image can appear anytime.

Comment: running some code until a condition is met is usually done in a while loop.

Comment: So what you're saying is, you want to do something [while](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) a condition is being checked.

Comment: @Kraay99 No, I want the condition to be checked for a long time

Answer (score 1):

I have done something similar,
Using the autoit module to find the window title and button name

```
import autoit,time
while True:
    try:
        autoit.control_click("[TITLE:MTMS Update; CLASS:#32770]", "Button1")
        print("Clicked OK")
    except:
        time.sleep(30)
        pass
```